# ZK binder updating lists slow

Tags: spring, hibernate, list, data-binding, zk

For some time I have been working with ZK and now I have an application hosted in the cloud but this does not meet my performance expectations. My application uses ZK for the view, Hibernate for the interaction with the MySQL database and Spring for the management of beans related to database interaction.

Example scenario:

1. At initialization a list is retrieved from the database using hibernate (we are talking about max 200 objects, max 6 standard attributes). This takes some time, but is acceptable.
2. I add or delete objects from the list I use @NotifyChange("list") to tell the view that the list has changed.
3. The list is updated but this takes long, in my opinion (~2 seconds)

Step 3 takes about as long as step 1 which I don't understand, the Spring managed objects for database interaction have yet been initialized. Another thing to note is that I don't reload the entire list from the database when adding or deleting an object from the list; A local copy is kept of the objects in the spring managed bean @Autowired to my ViewModels. (Yes, potentially out of sync with the database, but in my case not much of an issue) But this eliminates hibernate/spring/database as the bottleneck, right?.

Also I ran this on the localhost, and of course that is faster but still not instant as I would expect/want.

Now I thought that it might have to do something with the creation and deletion of objects in java related to lists. I did research on how the ZK binder works and how objects are updated but I can't find anything about how the binder handles updates on lists.

Does anyone know how the ZK binder updates a list in the view when in the viewmodel the method is annotated with @NotifyChange("listA") ? Does it actually throw away the old list and sets the whole new list, or does it somehow have a merge on differences?

Also comments on what else could be the bottleneck are very welcome!

Thanks in advance,

Robert

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I assume you use `Listbox` to represent your list.
First you need to know, that zk uses the same data
structure for MVVM that it uses for MVC. This means
that it uses [`ListModel`](http://books.zkoss.org/wiki/ZK%20Developer%27s%20Reference/MVC/Model/List%20Model) and the [performance tips](http://books.zkoss.org/wiki/ZK%20Developer%27s%20Reference/Performance%20Tips/Listbox,%20Grid%20and%20Tree%20for%20Huge%20Data/Implement%20ListModel%20and%20TreeModel)
are usefull for MVVM as well.
Of course zk can't implement the standart model
in a way, that it fits everybodys needs.
So what you have to do is implement your own
model. Usually the best is to extend from [`ListModelList`](http://www.zkoss.org/javadoc/latest/zk/org/zkoss/zul/ListModelList.html).
This way you can smart update the list.

Comment: That seems like a good idea! I'll try to write my own list and merge on the setter of the list to reduce object creation/deletion. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

i work alot with ZK but i have never use @NotifyChange, when i want to reload the data of a grid or listbox I always render or load it all again. For me it works fine and fast in less than 1 second. Here is an example of my binding:
>
And yes, when the data changes i recall my method, load it again and works really fine.

```
    @Listen("onCreate = #listboxSolicitudes")
    public void loadList() {    
List<ConsultasSolicitudes> listaConsulta = null;
            listaConsulta = ConsultasSeguimientoDeSolicitudesDAO.obtenerSolicitudesAsignadas((Long) cbResponsable.getSelectedItem().getValue());
            ListModelList<ConsultasSolicitudes> solModel = new ListModelList<ConsultasSolicitudes>(listaConsulta);
            listboxSolicitudesAsignadas.setModel(solModel);
}
```

Maybe this can help you, but something must be wrong if it´s taking that long.

Comment: Well yea, but what you are describing is MVC, I am using MVVM. I use MVVM because my application needs a lot of databinding and using a viewmodel for that is more suited and gives more options. Thanks nevertheless for your reply